# How can I use an argument in a string in a bash function

Tags: string, bash, function, arguments

I try:

```
ctests() {
    curl -X POST \
        http://route.to.host/cucumber/execute-tests \
        -H 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
        -d '{ "text": "cucumber! alltests products=$1" }'
}
```

And want to call this like

```
> ctests someproduct
```

But $1 wont resolve. I tried ${1}, but its the same.
Is there a nice solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `$1` doesn't resolve because you are using single-ticks `'` which prohibit variable resolution.

use double-ticks (`"`) instead (you'll have to escape the double-quotes inside the double-quotes; or use single-quotes within the double-quotes; depending on your context)

```
ctests() {
    curl -X POST \
        http://route.to.host/cucumber/execute-tests \
        -H 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
        -d "{ \"text\": \"cucumber! alltests products=$1\" }"
}
```

quoting `bash(1)`:

> **QUOTING**
>
> [...]
>
> Enclosing  characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $ [...]